# Android Firebase filter one database based on children of other database

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have 2 databases. One is blogposts and other is following. Now I want to retrieve only those data from blogposts whose users are followed by me (like what we do in any social media app). My blogposts' posts are of the format:

[image]

and the following database of the format:

[image]

As we can see, I want to get the values from following (values are userids)  and compare them with the userId in each post in blogpost. If I find out that they are equal, I get the query and use that in firebaserecycleradapter.
I know how to use firebaserecycleradapter. Please tell me how to get the query.

Comment: I think you will need to do 2 queries, first get userId from BlogPost and then get userIds from second database as a list or something else

Comment: 2 queries works. or you may use cloud function to create a rest api (with 2 queries), so you will only open one end point to the android device. Easier to call one API if you want to support both android and iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly as @AssetBekbossynov, the most efficient way, I can think from the top of my head then that would be, doing two queries.

One to find the userId from the `Following` database and then the other one which you would have to do to loop and search in `BlogPosts` database.

I can give you some example code here, which might help you code your requirement precisely:

```java
reference.orderByChild("UserId").equalTo(userIdYouWantToSearch).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                             // do what you want
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { // ToDo: do something for errors

                        }
                  )};
```

And the other query which you would want to do would be for the `Following` database, which may look something like this:

```java
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                  // retrieve the userId you want
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }


        });
```

Comment: No worries, glad to help :)